# Is "bitten" the correct word choice in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar

I believe that "bitten" – not "bit" – is the correct word in each sentence below. Am I right?

*I was bitten by the love bug.*

*Joe said, "I got bitten by a mosquito."*

*The dog had bitten me.*

*I had been bitten by a dog.*

Comment: ~1,140,000 results: https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=ccMRU5SSFq2kiAeBqIGIDA&ved=0CBoQ1S4#q=%22been+bit+by%22

Comment: The past participle in this case is not *bitten* alone, but **bit·ten (bĭt′n) or bit** -- http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bite

Comment: @kris But, bitten is perfectly appropriate in all of those situations.

Comment: @DavidM Why not? Both are acceptable.

Comment: @Kris I never actually stated that *bit* wasn't acceptable.  I merely stated that *bitten was acceptable* and appropriate.  Although I would say that for most speakers of AmE, bitten is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Bitten is the past participle of bite.  Hence, it is appropriate in all of those situations.

Bit is the past tense of bite, but may also be used as the past participle of bite. [See reference here.](http://grammarist.com/usage/bit-bitten/) It's use is rare in formal English where bitten is the preferred form. There are dialectal preferences that may govern this decision, though.

Comment: re: pp., see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154807/is-stunk-correct-in-his-feet-stunk#comment321515_154807

Comment: Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: Although, in some dialects, "bit" is used as well.

Comment: @nxx I never said it wasn't. I just said bitten was appropriate.

Comment: @David M I know! Just addressing the OP's reference to "bit". Not directed at you in particular.

Comment: -1. *Bit* is not a past participle of *bite* in Standard English; it's dialectal. The answer implies that both have equal validity and application.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Multiple dictionaries say that bit is a past participle. I stated that bitten is preferred in AmE.  And, what defines *standard English*?  I have made no implication of equality, what do you read the word preferred to mean????

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+bit%2Chas+bitten%2Chas+been+bit%2Chas+been+bitten&year_start=1900&year_end=2014&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20bitten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20bit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20bitten%3B%2Cc0) -- most of the *has bit* references are to *bit* as a noun. And it wasn't *prefer* which was the issue, but the two previous sentences.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have edited for clarity.  I hope this convinces you to withdraw your down vote and settles your ill-ease with my answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm quoting you in my answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32943/2818) but not sure I'm not **mis** quoting you (i.e. out of context)

Comment: @Laure I think that's fine (thanks!) But perhaps I should simply have marked that question as a duplicate of this one. Nobody's perfect!